# ggplot facetting using group_by

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, facet

Say I have measured some values in two experiments, a toy example in R being:

```
set.seed(9) 
df <- data.frame(
    exp=c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10)),
    value=runif(20,0,3))
```

I then assign the categorial variable `level` based on `value`:

```
require("dplyr") 
df <- df %>% mutate(level = ifelse(value<1, "low", ifelse(value>2, "high", "intermediate")))
```

I can display a `geom_point()` geom (`ggplot2` package) of `value`for the two `exp` groups:

```
require("ggplot2")
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(exp), y=value))+geom_point()
```

My problem is:
How can I break down the display with `facet_wrap()` by `level` so that I get a 3x3 graph of `geom_point()`'s with the nine combinations of `level`for the two `exp` (e.g. "high", "intermediate" and "low" vertically for experimment 1 and horizontally for experiment 2. In other words, the upper left graph are those `value`which are "high" in experiment 1 and 2; first row second column graph are those that are "high" in experiment 1 and "intermediate" in experiment 2 etc). Can I somehow use `group_by()` in the ggplot2 call, or will I have to make `level.exp1` and `level.exp2`variables to facet around  ?

UPDATE:
Seems I didnt explain it properly, so to clarify what I need: I would like to `facet_wrap()` instead of repeating this code 9 times with different `filter()` conditions (i.e. for all 9 combinations of `level`in experiment 1 and 2):

```
df  %>% filter((exp==1 & level=="high") | (exp==2 & level=="high")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(exp), y=value))+geom_point()
```

A handmade madeup and not related to `df`above and with fake legends may give an impression of what I want:

[image]
There must be a gentle solution - I could not figure out a a `dcast()` solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if typo or not, but you didn't actually assigned `level` variable to `df`... It also seems like you only have 6 combinations here

Comment: Based on your description, is it correct that you want to plot some of the values multiple times? ("In other words, the upper left graph are those valuewhich are "high" in experiment 1 and 2; first row second column graph are those that are "high" in experiment 1 and "intermediate" in experiment 2" -> "high" values of experiement 1 are duplicated?)

Comment: @David Arenburg, you are absolutely correct - i edited accordingly . Thanks. But I have 9 graphs since some data are dublicated, see  docendo discimus comment.

Comment: @ docendo discimus, yes thats correct. All panels have the same data for exp 1 row-wise (e.g. "high" values in row 1), while column-wise exp 2 data are the same (e.g. "high" values in column 1 etc). Maybe the solution could be `dcast()` to actually make new level columns for each exp and `facet_wrap()` with these ?

Comment: I still struggle to understand the 9 (not 6) different combinations.

Comment: Thanks for strugling. If you repeat the code in my UPDATE and change filter conditions (always as ("exp1" condition| "exp2" condition)) you have the 9 combinations of level: (high, high), (high, interm), (high, low), (interm, high), ... , (low, low) giving you 9 plots in the end

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. I think the key is that there should be some id that observations share between experiment 1 and experiment 2.

```r
set.seed(9) 
df <- 
  data.frame(
    id = rep(1:100, 2),
    # adding exp_ bc this will be the column name in the next step
    exp = paste0("exp_", rep(1:2, each = 100)),
    value = runif(200, 0, 3)
  ) %>% 
  # this will pivot the data into a column for exp_1 and exp_2
  spread(exp, value) %>% 
  mutate(
    level_1 = case_when(exp_1 < 1 ~ "low", exp_1 > 2 ~ "high", TRUE ~ "intermediate"),
    level_2 = case_when(exp_2 < 1 ~ "low", exp_2 > 2 ~ "high", TRUE ~ "intermediate"),
    # reorder the high med low categories
    level_1 = fct_relevel(level_1, "high", "intermediate", "low"),
    level_2 = fct_relevel(level_2, "high", "intermediate", "low")
  )


# plot it
ggplot(df, aes(x = exp_1, y = exp_2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(level_1~level_2) +
  labs(
    x = "Experiment 1",
    y = "Experiment 2"
  )
```

[image]

There is a new function in the works that will allow you to create the labels and pivot both the values and the labels together but it's not out yet
https://www.r-bloggers.com/pivoting-data-frames-just-got-easier-thanks-to-pivot_wide-and-pivot_long/